# java loop not printing inputstream data after first iteration

Tags: java, loops, inputstream

I have a java program that connects to an online resource, reads the data, then parses for a specific piece of information (it is the number of active reddit accounts viewing a certain page).

I want to automate this process to repeat it at a given interval (I set the interval to 5 seconds just to see if it is working). The program then prints this number to a file, on a different line each time. I know that the main loop is iterating, because my `output.txt` file has several lines, but it only finds and prints the number on the first iteration.

```
package redditreader3;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RedditReader3 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
int i = 1;
String host = args[0]; // www.reddit.com

String resource = args[1]; // /r/toronto/about.json     

final int HTTP_PORT = 80;
String command = "GET " + resource + " HTTP/1.1\n" + "Host:"  + host
   + "\n\n";

    /* This command requests reddit for the source code of the resource in args[1] at its host, args[0] to be printed through HTTP. */

Socket socket = new Socket(host, HTTP_PORT);

    InputStream instream = socket.getInputStream();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(instream);

    OutputStream outstream = socket.getOutputStream();

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outstream);

File file = new File("output.txt");

    FileOutputStream F_outstream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        PrintStream F_printstream = new PrintStream(F_outstream);

 /* Now that the connection has been established and all of the objects
    are connected to each other, the command may be sent and the data 
    transfer may begin. */

String ActiveAccountsData = ("\"accounts_active\": (\\d+)");

String ActiveAccountsDataFOUND;

Pattern ActiveAccountsPattern = Pattern.compile(ActiveAccountsData);

Matcher ActiveAccountsMatcher; 

String input;

while(i <= 4)
{

    out.print(command);
    out.flush();

    while(in.hasNextLine())
    {
        input = in.nextLine();
        ActiveAccountsMatcher = ActiveAccountsPattern.matcher(input);

        if(ActiveAccountsMatcher.find())
        {
            ActiveAccountsDataFOUND = ActiveAccountsMatcher.group(1);
            F_printstream.println(ActiveAccountsDataFOUND); 
            break;
        }
    }
    i++;
    F_printstream.println();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
}
}
```

I was thinking maybe the `in.hasNextLine()` value is stuck somewhere and needs to be updated, but I can't find a method that will return it to the beginning of the input from the website.

Comment: You have to debug your program to better localize the source of the problem. It is bad to expose us to unnecessary details. Secondly, the problem will be obvious, once you debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your loop around the *entire* method.  for each iteration you need to re-establish the connection and parse the stream.

note, you would be better off using a HttpURLConnection instead of using a direct socket call (that way you won't have to handle the http header yourself, etc).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  Would you have a link to a tutorial or something that uses a HttpURLConnection? I am unfamiliar with it.

Comment: @1saac - i bet google has _tons_ of links to tutorials for using HttpURLConnection.

Answer (score 0):

You should issue a new HTTP GET request to get the updated data in every 5 seconds. i.e. move your InputStream/Scanner codes inside the loop.

Besides, you might want to use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) instead of operating the raw socket.

Answer (score 0):

Remove below lines from the current position and

```
Socket socket = new Socket(host, HTTP_PORT);

InputStream instream = socket.getInputStream();

    Scanner in = new Scanner(instream);

OutputStream outstream = socket.getOutputStream();

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outstream);
```

Change the code to below but dont forget to close the resources (inputstreams and output streams):

```
while(i <= 4)
{
  Socket socket = new Socket(host, HTTP_PORT);



InputStream instream = socket.getInputStream();

    Scanner in = new Scanner(instream);

OutputStream outstream = socket.getOutputStream();

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outstream); 

out.print(command);
out.flush();

while(in.hasNextLine())
{
    input = in.nextLine();
    ActiveAccountsMatcher = ActiveAccountsPattern.matcher(input);

    if(ActiveAccountsMatcher.find())
    {
        ActiveAccountsDataFOUND = ActiveAccountsMatcher.group(1);
        F_printstream.println(ActiveAccountsDataFOUND); 
        break;
    }
}
i++;
F_printstream.println();
//close resources
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Your scanner is doing as expected. It's going through the stream and printing the content. 
What you want to do is to rewind the stream. You can do it using reset on the Inputstream (see javadoc for details). You might need to create a new Scanner

Comment: If I rewind the stream, will it still be inputting the data for the newest request to the website? Also, can I declare a new scanner inside the loop? I thought this would not work because the second declaration would have the same name as the first.